# PHP - if/else if is ignoring database result to authenticate request

Tags: php

I'm trying to lookup user-data while the user is trying to authenticate his account with my mysql database. The function checks if the user-account is disabled and activated before starting the password lookup.

My problem: Even when I store the value **1** inside the disabled row, the user would still authenticate even tho the `if` row should `return 'disabled';` Which shouldn't let the user authenticate.

The database structure looks like the following:

```
id | username | password | email | activation_id | activated | disabled
```

I've been logging the data inside the `$rows` array into a textfile on a authentication request which skipped the `if($rows[0]['activated'] == '0')` and `else if($rows[0]['disabled'] == '1')` and it looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [activated] => 0
            [disabled] => 1
        )
)
```

Authenticate function:

```
// Authenticate account function
function authenticate_account($username, $password)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
        exit();
        return false;
    }

    $userDataSql = "SELECT activated, disabled FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmtData = $mysqli->prepare($userDataSql);
    $stmtData->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmtData->execute();
    $result = $stmtData->get_result();
    $rows = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $stmtData->close();

    if($rows[0]['activated'] == '0')
    {
        return 'activate';
    }
    else if($rows[0]['disabled'] == '1')
    {
        return 'disabled';
    }
    else
    {
        $userAuthVerificationSql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        $stmtAuthVerification = $mysqli->prepare($userAuthVerificationSql);
        $stmtAuthVerification->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmtAuthVerification->execute();
        $stmtAuthVerification->bind_result($userHash);

        while ($stmtAuthVerification->fetch())
        {
            if ($username !== false && password_verify($password, $userHash)) 
            {
                $mysqli->close();
                return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                $mysqli->close();
                return false;
            }
        }

        $stmtAuthVerification->close();
    }
}
```

Code which handles the returned values:

```
$authenticate_account = $authenticate->authenticateAccount();

if($authenticate_account == true)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('location: /authenticated/index.php');
    exit();
}
else if($authenticate_account == 'activate')
{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Error, your account is not activated. Please activate it by clicking on the link in the sent email!</div>';
}
else if($authenticate_account == 'disabled')
{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Error, your account is dissabled. Please contact the support!</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Error, wrong user/password combination. Please try again!</div>';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Note that a string will evaluate to `true` in a loose comparison. How are you using the return value of your function?

Comment: Updated the question, contains the return handling now

Comment: Change `if($authenticate_account == true)` to `if($authenticate_account === true)` because string evalutes to true, ex. 'disabled' == true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if($authenticate_account == true)
```

Note that:

```
if('any non-empty string' == true)
```

will evaluate to `true`, so that applies to almost all of your return values, `true`, `'disabled'` and `'activate'`.

Use `===` instead of `==` to avoid that; then you check for both the `true` value and the `boolean` type.

Comment: It worked! Wow i didn't knew that. Learning something new every day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking off your code (it also avoids nesting):

```
if (!$rows[0]['activated'])
    return 'activate';
else if ($rows[0]['disabled'])
    return 'disabled';

*Do the authentication here
```

It checks if the row is activated and if it is disabled. If it passed, you'll just continue running the authentication stuff.